# Unicode path string operation truncates string

Tags: c#, unicode, path

I want to open a document from a web application but the string operation I apply in order to get the path in the correct format does crazy stuff and truncates the string. The correct string should look like this:

```
file://\\corp.root.int\dax-emea$\DAX\ES75\Certificates\Whatsoever\DOC0630381.DOC
```

With the portion belonging to the share (\\corp.root.int...) being read from a gridview I do:

```
string path = @"file://" + Gridview.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
```

When I try to open that path, I get this error:

```
Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted? (file://\\corp.root.int\dax-emea$\DAX\ES7)
```

The path gets truncated after 40 characters! The strange thing is that the web app worked perfectly while being on another server. Now, that I moved it to a newer server this problem showed up.

---

I am pretty sure that this MUST be related to the @"file//" + operation. To prove this I eliminated the @"file://" portion and did this:

```
string path = Gridview.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text + "Test"
```

This causes this error message

```
Was it moved, renamed, or deleted? (\\corp.root.int\...\DOC0630381.DOCtest)
```

The path is later opened in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Comment: How are you putting it into the gridview

Comment: Does the Gridview show entire string?

Comment: What is the UI Framework used?

Comment: Maybe `Cell.Text` return the displayed text that can be truncated. Try with `Cell.Value` to get the real value.

Comment: @DanielA.White: that (dynamic) portion is taken from an SQL Query and reflects the correct path

Comment: I added some more details in order to reply to your comments

Comment: Why forward slashes and backwards slashes : file://\\  Should be just "\\"

Comment: @jdweng: you are right, the slashes are enough. I guess this nomenclature was necessary when I ran the application on Internet Explorer. Unfortunately it still doesn't open the file. Unfortunately no error message pops up as the opening of the file is hanging for an unknown reason

Comment: The dollar sign after machine name indicates you are an admin on both local and remote machines.  The credentials have to be verified against a password server.  The delay is probably due to the credentials check not completing.  Not sure why.